# How to get value from PHP generated <select>?

Tags: php, dropdown

I have a drop-down list with PHP generated options. I am trying to capture the selected value as I need to pass it to another function. Normally, $_POST['patient_dropdown'] would work fine but I could not make it work for my case. Is there any way to capture the selected value into

```
<select name="patient_dropdown" id="patient_dropdown" class="patientform">
    <?php 
        $response = "";
        $client = new SoapClient("healthinfosys.wsdl");
        $response = $client->getAllPatientsEntry();
        echo $response;
    ?>
</select>
```

For your reference, here is the function being used to generate the options for the dropdown -

```
function getAllPatientsEntry(){
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    $dbname = "healthinfosys";

    //Create connection
    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

    //Check connection
    if($conn->connect_error){
        die("Connection failed " . $conn->connect_error);
    }


    $sql = "SELECT * FROM patient_info";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if($result->num_rows > 0){

        //Output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            $output = $output . "<option value=\"\">".$row['patient_name']."</option>";
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "0 results";
    }

    $conn->close();
    return $output;
}
```

Comment: PHP has nothing to do with it. If you aren't making valid HTML it won't work. Did you check your source to see if your HTML was valid?

Comment: Your values in the options are empty string.

Comment: Silly me. Trying that now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to assign a value to your options:

```
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $output = $output.'<option value="'.$row['patient_name'].'">'.$row['patient_name']."</option>";
        // or $row['patient_id'] or something else
    }
```

Comment: Trying it now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign a value for your options like below
Your code with problem

```
 //Output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $output = $output . "<option value=\"\">".$row['patient_name']."</option>";
    }
```

Changed to this

```
 //Output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
        $output = $output . "<option value='".$row['patient_name']."'>".$row['patient_name']."</option>";
    }
```

Comment: Yes, I did that as suggested by the others. Thank you anyway, Joseph!